# Set Default Server Timezone in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

I want to set time zone in server. Similar we have in mule 3
https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-properly-set-the-TimeZone-in-Mule-Mule-Runtime-and-CloudHub

But in mule 4, i don't see a way to call class file outside flow. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

One way i found is setting the -Duser.timezone= in VM arguments. But still looking for way at program level

Answer (score 0):

To call Java classes in Mule 4 you need to add the [Java Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/java/java-module) to your project and use it to call the method. If you want to use the Spring configuration instead of calling Java from a flow, then you need to add the [Spring Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/spring/spring-module). Note that you have to put the Spring bean configuration in its own pure Spring XML file. Mule 4 XML files are not Spring XML files like in Mule 3. That means the Spring XML file must not have a `<mule>` tag. You need to reference the Spring XML in the Mule XML (example: `<spring:config name="springConfig" files="beans.xml" />`).

See the examples in the Spring Module documentation if you are not familiar with Spring.